# Como obtener datos del usuario relacionado con el mismo modelo en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

¿Como puedo obtener los datos de otro usuario, al que se hace referencia desde el mismo modelo usuario en Laravel?

Teniendo en cuenta que user tiene estas columnas en su migración:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {   

    $table->increments('id');

    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('surname')->nullable();
    $table->string('email');
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();

    $table->integer('banned_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('banned_by')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->timestamp('banned_at')->nullable();

    $table->integer('created_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->integer('deleted_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('deleted_by')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->softDeletes();

    $table->unique(['email', 'deleted_at']);

});
```

El modelo User tiene (entre otros similares) el siguiente método (nótese que se referencia a si mismo):

```
public function created_by()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'created_by');
}
```

En el controlador:

```
$user = User::find($id);
return view('ejemplo', compact('user'));
```

Y en la vista:

```
{{ $user->created_by()->name }}
```

Pero devuelve un error de que no es capaz de encontrar la propiedad.

Comment: si es una colección necesitas recorrerlo con un foreach

Comment: @AlfredoPaz No es una colección, `User::find($id)` devuelve un único usuario con el id correspondiente. De la misma forma, `created_by()` está relacionado con un único usuario de la misma tabla, en este caso el usuario que ha creado a ese usuario (sólo ciertos usuarios pueden crear a otros usuarios).

Comment: Intenta cambiando el nombre de tu funcion: `created_by()` por createdBy(), y en todo caso seria bueno que publiques todo el error.

Comment: @Shassain Cambiar el nombre de la función no ha servido para solucionar el problema. El error es uno standard de Laravel que dice Undefined property.

Comment: @SergiC, a mi parecer solo es problema del nombre, intenta con un nombre totalmente difirente y sin guion bajo, al parecer se esta confundiendo con la columna `created_by` que tienes en tu tabla, y te recomiendo NO poner la siguiente linea en tus migraciones: `$table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users');`, ya que no podras crear ni un solo usuario.

Comment: @Shassain ¿Podrías explicar más detalladamente porque crees que no podré crear usuarios si utilizo esa linea en mis migraciones? De momento he podido crear más de 1000 usuarios (para hacer pruebas) usando seeds y Faker sin ningún tipo de problema, eso sí poniendo el campo `created_by` a `null` (después cambiándolo a un id existente para probar la funcionalidad). Nota que el usuario 1, el administrador, vendrá creado por defecto, y a partir de él se podrán crear otros administradores o usuarios por debajo de éste.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta obtener los datos así:

```
$user = User::with('created_by')->find($id);
```

Y obtienes los datos con:

```
{{ $user->created_by()->first()->name }}
```

Comment: De momento es la solución que me ha funcionado, pero en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/172232/90206 se comenta que no es muy correcto.

Answer (score 0):

como en tu base de datos tienes un campo llamado `created_by` al momento de usar `$user->created_by` te va a devolver el valor que tienes en el campo `created_by` y no la relación.

En cambio si utilizas `$user->created_by()` te va a devolver un objeto `belongsTo`, ya que estas utilizando directamente el metodo `created_by()`.

**SOLUCIÓN:**

Cambia el nombre de tu método created_by() por uno que no sea igual al nombre de los campos que tienes en la base de datos. Por ejemplo:

```
public function createdBy()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'created_by');
}
```

**NOTA:**

Veo que en la vista usa algo como esto `{{ $user->created_by()->name }}`, no es correcto, debido a que estas llamando directamente al metodo de tu modelo y te va a retornar un objeto `belongsTo`. Lo correcto seria  `{{ $user->createdBy->name }}` Sin los paréntesis

Comment: duda ¿por qué lo debe eliminar?

Comment: Creo que di una respuesta apresurada, me podrías mostrar tu migracion de la tabla users?

Comment: @LuisOzuna He editado la pregunta original para añadir la migración de la tabla users. Ten en cuenta que, por requerimientos del sistema, tengo más de una relación con la propia tabla users.

Comment: @SergiC checa la respuesta. espero y te sirva cual quier duda me la hace saber.